# How to do search filter in two level menu with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, search, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to implement filter to two level menu.

My menu is structured like this:

<      Search Filter        >

California V

```
  View all
  San Francisco
  Los Angles
```

Florida V

```
  View all
  Miami
  Tallahassee
```

So If I type 'ia' in filter it should show like this:

Californ**ia** v

```
  View all
```

Florida v

```
  View all
  M**ia**mi
```

I have two ng-repeats for states and cities nested.

Pseudo code:

`<filter ng-model=search.$></filter>
      <div ng-repeat="states in usa.states | filter : search.states">
          <b>{{states}}</b>
       <div ng-repeat="cities in states | filter : search.cities">
          <b>{{cities}}</b>
       </div>
      </div>`

This is not working properly. Is there a way I can create custom filter functions for two level menu? I know how to do with one level. Could someone point me in right direction how to do with this kind of requirement?

Thanks!

Comment: How about passing a function to your first filter instead of "search.states"? That function would search the name of the state, and the name of its cities. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: I tried like this: '$scope.searchFilter = function (name) {
     var keyword = new RegExp($scope.nameFilter, 'i');
     return !$scope.nameFilter || keyword.test(states) || keyword.test(cities);
 }; ' But its not filtering states, only filtering cities.

Answer (score 0):

your ngRepeat are kinda weird... shouldn't it be something like:

```
<filter ng-model="nameFilter"></filter>
<div ng-repeat="state in usa.states | filter:nameFilter">
   <b>{{state.name}}</b>
   <div ng-repeat="city in state.cities | filter:nameFilter">
      <b>{{city.name}}</b>
   </div>
</div>
```

And then, you can replace the 1st "searchFilterValue" by a function:

```
$scope.searchFilter = function (state) {
  if (!$scope.nameFilter) {
    return true;
  }
  var keyword = new RegExp($scope.nameFilter, 'i');
  if (keyword.test(state.name)) {
    return true;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < state.cities.length; ++i) {
    if (keyword.test(state.cities[i].name)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```